# Motion sensor on Gideros mobile

Tags: gideros

Is it possible to use motion sensors with 'Gideros Mobile SDK'? Any piece of code / link to tutorial/example will be helpful. I am writing for Android if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gideros supports Accelerometer, Geolocation and Gyroscope, so no problem there.
When you download Gideros, there are built in examples under Hardware section where you can both check the code and test run them on device